# Least pair of numbers having at least $k$ distinct prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

[Consecutive numbers with less than $k$ prime factors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290893/consecutive-numbers-with-less-than-k-prime-factors/1296497#1296497)

shows that for every $k$, there is a pair $(n/n+1)$, such that $n$ and $n+1$
both have at least $k$ distinct prime factors.

The object is to find the least such pair depending on $k$.

```
? for(k=2,6,n=1;while(1-(omega(n)>=k)*(omega(n+1)>=k),n=n+1);print(k,"   ",n,"
  ",n+1,"    ",factor(n),"     ",factor(n+1)))

2   14   15    [2, 1; 7, 1]     [3, 1; 5, 1]
3   230   231    [2, 1; 5, 1; 23, 1]     [3, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1]
4   7314   7315    [2, 1; 3, 1; 23, 1; 53, 1]     [5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 19, 1]
5   254540   254541    [2, 2; 5, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1; 89, 1]     [3, 1; 7, 1; 17, 1;
 23, 1; 31, 1]
6   11243154   11243155    [2, 1; 3, 1; 13, 1; 17, 1; 61, 1; 139, 1]        [5, 1;7, 1; 11, 1; 19, 1; 29, 1; 53, 1]
7   965009045   965009046    [5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1; 23, 1; 83, 1; 101, 1]    [2, 1; 3, 1; 17, 1; 29, 1; 41, 1; 73, 1; 109, 1]
```

- Who can extend this table ?
- Is there an efficient method to find the smallest pair ?

Comment: The smallest examples for $k$ distinct prime factors for both neighbors are listed here: http://oeis.org/A093548/b093548.txt . Few examples (probably not the least ones) for $k=12,\ldots,18$ are written in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703343/1-as-difference-of-composites-with-same-number-of-prime-factors-and-smallest-e/2704818#2704818.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
8 65893166030 65893166031 [2 5 17 19 43 67 73 97] [3 7 11 29 31 41 71 109]
```

I didn't find a clever solution, and it still takes a very long time.  Two small changes:

- Walk `n` linearly, calculating omega only once.  One has to handle the case of a value satisfying more than one `k`, but that's easy.  This means only one omega call as well as not starting the search over for each `k`.
- Use Perl/ntheory, which has a faster omega than Pari/GP.  Only 2-3x but that adds up.

Comment: Well done! Do you continue the search ?

Comment: For now, yes.  This really feels like something that ought to be approached from the other direction (build up from small factors rather than walking composites factoring each one).  Which was your question...  I thought it'd be interesting to see how far brute force worked.

Comment: The pair $9568867814219 /9568867814220$ is an example for $k=9$

Comment: The pair $12454657911382049 /12454657911382050$ is an example for $k=10$

Comment: The pair $225397828721132073149 /225397828721132073150$ is an example for $k=11$

Comment: $19874410493002274730270329/19874410493002274730270330$ is an example for $k=12$