# $1$ as difference of composites with same number of prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I noticed and found only first three cases:

We can write $1$ as difference of two composites that have one prime factor $$3^2-2^3=1$$

and as difference of two composites that have two prime factors $$3\cdot 5 - 7\cdot 2 = 1$$

and as difference of two composites that have three prime factors $$2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 43-7 \cdot 13 \cdot 17=1$$

I believe that this holds for every $k \in \mathbb N$, that is, that for every $k \in \mathbb N$ there exist composites $a_k$ and $b_k$ that have exactly $k$ prime factors and are such that we have $a_k-b_k=1$.

> Is my belief true? Is this known? What is known about all of this and similar problems? Can someone find solutions for some larger $k$´s?

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296532/least-pair-of-numbers-having-at-least-k-distinct-prime-factors) by Peter where he wants that all prime factors are different.

Comment: I'm going to bet this hasn't been proven and it's likely quite a challenge to prove.

Comment: @vrugtehagel, perhaps there's a more general theorem: for any pair of relatively prime integers $a$ and $b$ of opposite parity (so $2\mid ab$), there are (infinitely many?) primes $p\gt a$ and $q\gt b$ such that $|ap-bq|=1$. This has a Bezout's/Dirichlet feel to it.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296532/least-pair-of-numbers-having-at-least-k-distinct-prime-factors for $k=4,5,...,12.$

Comment: Another example for 3 prime factors $3\times7\times11-2\times5\times23=1$

Comment: I have found that $1042 - 1041 = 1$ and $1043 - 1042 = 1$ such that $1041 = 3\times 347,$ $1042 = 2\times 521$ and $1043 = 7\times 149$.

Comment: @user477343 Very nice, so we have a successive pair.

Comment: @JamesArathoon Yes, there could be an infinite number of examples for every $k$.

Comment: I have found another successive pair as you say: $1643 - 1642 = 1$ and $1642 - 1641 = 1$ such that $1641 = 3\times 547,$ $1642 = 2\times 821$ and $1643 = 31\times 53$.

Comment: @user477343 We can call your findings "double pairs". Can you find a "triple pair", that is $a_k,,b_k=a_k+1,c_k=b_k+1,d_k=c_k+1$?

Comment: Just did: I have also found a successive **triplet** with $445, 446, 447, 448$.

Comment: The first pair greater than $10$ is $(14, 15)$. The first pair greater than $10^2$ is $(111, 112)$. The first pair greater than $10^3$ is $(1001, 1002)$. The first pair greater than $10^4$ is $(10013, 10014)$. **Fun Fact:** All the numbers between the prime numbers $9413$ and $9419$ are numbers with the special property you discovered! I will stop commenting now because it might just fill the page, but I want to see if this is the largest prime gap such that every number in it has the same amount of prime factors (three). First pair of three prime factors found thus far is $(8732,8733,8734)$

Comment: Oh, and one more comment: what do you wish to call these numbers? I am constructing a partial answer to stop too many comments, and what would you like me to refer to these numbers as?

Comment: If $$a_{1,k},a_{2,k}=a_{1,k}+1,...a_{l,k}=a_{(l-1),k}+1$$ are $l$ successive composites that have exactly $k$ prime factors we can call them "amazing $(k,l$)- composituple(s)", if you like that name? Or just "$(k,l$)- composituple(s)".

Comment: @user477343 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2701500/1-as-difference-of-n-successive-composites-that-have-exactly-two-prime-facto

Comment: I will denote this as $(k,l)_C$ for simplicity :)

Comment: there are plenty of cases when the difference has just two prime factors. ex $2*11-3*7=1$, $2*17-3*11=1$...I suppose it gets more complicated when the number of prime factors involved increases.

Answer (score 1):

I had too many comments, so I will put it in a partial answer, referring to the special numbers in the OP's question as $(k, l)$ composituples:

---

**Definition:** If $$a_{1,k},a_{2,k} = a_{1,k}+1,\ldots a_{l,k} = a_{(l-1),k}+1$$ are $l$ successive composites that have exactly $k$ prime factors, they are known as $(k,l)$ compo-situples. The set of these is denoted as $(k,l)_C\ni a_{l,k}$. I have investigated the following kind of set for prime pairs $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ such that I want to find the largest value of $l$ for a given $k$. $$(k,l)_C = \big\{\{p_n + 1,\ldots, p_{n+1} - 1\} : \text{card}(k,l) = l\,\land\,\Omega(a_{l,k}) = k\big\}.$$ Thus far, the largest value of $l$ has been $7$ such that $$(2, 7)_C =\{212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219\}$$ for $k = 2$. Whether or not these are the smallest elements, I do not know.

---

**Questions in regards to composituples that I have found:**

- The smallest value of $k$ and $l$ have to be $2$ by definition. Therefore, the smallest composituple is $(2,2)_C = \{14, 15\}$. But how many composituples are there, I do not know. My guess is in-finitely many.
- Let $(2,3)_C = \{403, 404, 405\}$, then are these the smallest elements?
- Let $(3, 3)_C = \{986,987,988\}$, then are these the smallest elements?
- Let $(2, 4)_C = \{445, 446, 447, 448\}$, then are these the smallest elements?
- Let $(2, 5)_C = \{54, 55, 56, 57, 58\}$, then these *are* the smallest elements.
- Let $(3, 5)_C = \{8214, 8215, 8216, 8217, 8218\}$, then are these the smallest elements?
- Let $(2, 6)_C = \{323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329\}$, then are these the smallest elements?
- Composituples $(3,4)_C,\,(3, 6)_C$ and $(3,7)_C$ have not been found yet.

---

Oddly enough, I have not written a program to find these. I simply just went [here](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt) to look at prime numbers, and then I went [here](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) to decompose the composites in between a given prime pair.

This is strictly a partial answer, or rather, a very long comment as opposed to an answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703343/1-as-difference-of-composites-with-same-number-of-prime-factors-and-smallest-e

Comment: @Shalom hahah thank you. It relieved me of some efforts :)

Comment: Do you wanna chat?

Comment: @Shalom perhaps some other time. I am busy today and tomorrow as well. The following day from that is Sunday for me so I'll be good and might be on the math.SE for a while. Would u want to chat then? I can dedicate that time to finding the $(k, l)$ composituples.