# Generalized Dirichlet theorem for primes in arithmetic sequences

Tags: number-theory, distribution-of-primes

Dirichlet's theorem for arithmetic sequences of primes states that if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then there exists an infinite number of prime numbers of the form $a+kb$.

My question is can we conclude, for similar $a$ and $b$ coprime and a fixed number $n$, there are an infinite number of numbers exactly the product of $n$ primes of the form $a+kb$?

(My question is motivated from thinking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703343/1-as-difference-of-composites-with-same-number-of-prime-factors-and-smallest-e).)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The product will not have the required form, but that's not much of a problem. Take _one_ prime of the form $a+kb$ and $(n-1)$ primes of the form $1+kb$ (of which there are also infinitely many); then the product will be of the form $a+kb$, and we're done.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: maybe I misread the question but my interpretation of it was: are there infinite integers $m$ such that $$ m = \prod_{k=1}^{n} p_k $$ with the $p_k$s being distinct primes of the form $a+kb$? Yes, of course.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio My interpretation was different: are there infinite integers $m$ of the form $a+kb$, each being a product of exactly $n$ primes?

Comment: @IvanNeretin: oh, I see. Well, the answer is *clearly yes* in both cases.